# \DeclareOption does not work with my MikTex

Tags: latex, miktex

I wrote an cls-file for my latex-documents and it works like a charm with my texlive installation. But on my new Labtop, where I tried MiKTex, it ignores the declarations.

I'll only post the beginning of the cls here, else it would be a little much.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{merlinsTemplate}[2020/08/29 My custom story class]


\newif\ifgerman\germanfalse %Deutsch, sonst English
\newif\ifaV\aVfalse %a5, sonst a4
\newif\ifbg\bgfalse %mit Hintergrund, sonst ohne
\newif\ifoneside\onesidefalse % einseitig
\newif\ifnoParindent\noParindentfalse
\newif\iflua\luafalse   %a5, sonst a4
\newif\ifarticle\articlefalse   %typ article instead of book

\DeclareOption{german}{\germantrue}
\DeclareOption{a5}{\aVtrue}
\DeclareOption{background}{\bgtrue}
\DeclareOption{oneside}{\onesidetrue}
\DeclareOption{noParindent}{\noParindenttrue}
\DeclareOption{lua}{\luatrue}
\DeclareOption{article}{\articletrue}

\ProcessOptions


\ifarticle
    \LoadClass{article}
\else
    \ifoneside
        \LoadClass[oneside]{book}
    \else
        \LoadClass{book}
    \fi
\fi


\ifgerman
    \RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}
\else
    \RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\fi


\RequirePackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%multicols trennlinie
    \newcommand{\Cmctc}{gray!10}
%titlesec
    \newcommand{\Ctscc}{violet} % \chapter
    \newcommand{\Ctssc}{blue}   % \section
    \newcommand{\Ctsssc}{cyan}  % \subsection
    \newcommand{\Ctssssc}{teal} % \subsubsection
    \newcommand{\Ctspc}{purple} % \paragraph
%etoolbox : headrule:Tikz
    \newcommand{\Cshlco}{\Ctscc}
    \newcommand{\Cshlct}{black}
%fancyhdr chaptermark
    \newcommand{\Ccmc}{\Ctscc}


\RequirePackage{geometry}
    \ifaV
        \geometry{a5paper,left=12mm,right=12mm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2cm}
    \else
        \geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}
    \fi


\RequirePackage{titlesec}%to format headings
\ifarticle
    \titleformat{\section}
    {\scshape\huge\color{\Ctssc}}
    {\LARGE\thesection}{.5em}{}[\titlerule]
    
    \titleformat{\subsection}
    {\Large\scshape\color{\Ctsssc}}
    {\large\thesubsection}{.25em}{}[\titlerule]
    
    \titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\Large\scshape\color{\Ctssssc}}
    {\tiny\thesubsubsection}{.25em}{}
    
    \titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
    {\normalfont\scshape\color{\Ctspc}}
    {\theparagraph}{0em}{}
\else
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
        {\scshape\Huge\color{\Ctscc}}
        {\filleft\large\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
        {0ex}
        {\titlerule\vspace{0.75ex}\filright}
        [\vspace{0.5ex}\titlerule]
    
    \titleformat{\section}
        {\centering\scshape\huge\color{\Ctssc}}
        {\scriptsize\thesection}{.5em}{}[\titlerule]
    
    \titleformat{\subsection}
        {\centering\large\scshape\color{\Ctsssc}}
        {\scriptsize\thesubsection}{.25em}{}[\titlerule]
    
    \titleformat{\subsubsection}
        {\Large\scshape\color{\Ctssssc}}
        {\tiny\thesubsubsection}{.25em}{}
    
    \titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
        {\normalfont\scshape\color{\Ctspc}}
        {\theparagraph}{0em}{}
\fi


\RequirePackage{tikz}



\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
\ifarticle
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\textcolor{\Ccmc}{#1}}{}}
\else
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\textcolor{\Ccmc}{#1}}{}}
\fi


\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
    \renewcommand{\headrule}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}%
            \ifnumodd{\value{page}}
            {\shade[left color=\Cshlco, right color=\Cshlct, dashed] (0,0) rectangle (\headwidth,0.01);}
            {\shade[left color=\Cshlct, right color=\Cshlco, dashed] (0,0) rectangle (\headwidth,0.01);}
        \end{tikzpicture}}



\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}

\RequirePackage{array,ragged2e}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}  %tabellen
\RequirePackage{boldline}

\RequirePackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\usepackage{enumitem} %to change enumerate schichten

\RequirePackage{fontawesome}
\iflua
    \usepackage{fontspec}   % with lua
\fi 
\RequirePackage{fourier}
%\RequirePackage{graphics}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}   % Verlinkung des toc

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Umlaute für Deutsch direkt verwenden
\RequirePackage{lineno}
\RequirePackage{lipsum} % automatischer FillerText
\RequirePackage{longtable}
\RequirePackage{makecell}
\RequirePackage{marvosym}   % brief sonderzeichen
\RequirePackage{multicol}   % muli-columns 
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
    \def\columnseprulecolor{\color{\Cmctc}}
\RequirePackage{multirow} % Tables
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}

\RequirePackage{pifont} 

\RequirePackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % linksbündig mit Breitenangabe
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % zentriert mit Breitenangabe
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % rechtsbündig mit Breitenangabe
\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}
    \tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\RequirePackage{ulem}
\RequirePackage{wasysym}

\ifnoParindent
    \setlength{\parindent}{0em} %Einrücken unterdrücken von paragraph
    \renewcommand{\Ctscc}{red}
\else
    \renewcommand{\Ctscc}{blue}
\fi

\newdimen\R %für special marker
%\R=4pt
```

I call the class with:

```
\documentclass[german]{merlinsTemplate}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\chapter{ITS - Linux: Debian\\{\normalsize Mr. Lüthen}}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[22.12.20] \textit{Ferien}
    \item[29.12.20] \textit{Ferien}
    \item[05.01.21] \textit{Ferien}
    \item[12.01.21] 
\end{itemize}

\section{Installation of Debian{\tiny   18.08.2020, 25.08.2020, 01.09.2020}}
\subsection{Aufgabe}
    Ladida

\subsubsection{Installation eines Debian-Systems}

Für Ausbildungszwecke ist auf den privaten Laptops das Linux-Betriebssystem ...
\end{document}
```

On my computer with texlive **Content** translates to **Inhaltsverzeichnis** as it should, but on my MiKTex it is still **Content**.

The log on the MiKTex Labtop is: in a comment becaus it is too long for the body...

Has anyone an idea what is missing?

Comment: Can you post a [mre] of your document to make sure we test the same code and show the .log file of this document?

Answer (score 0):

Log (Part1)

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.12) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.12.22)  22 DEC 2020 10:59
entering extended mode
**./fullY1.tex
(fullY1.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-12-07> xparse <2020-03-03>
(merlinsTemplate.cls

LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class `merlinsTempl
ate',
               but the document class provides `merlinsTemplate'.

Document Class: merlinsTemplate 2020/08/29 My custom story class
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/base\book.cls
Document Class: book 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/base\bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count177
\c@chapter=\count178
\c@section=\count179
\c@subsection=\count180
\c@subsubsection=\count181
\c@paragraph=\count182
\c@subparagraph=\count183
\c@figure=\count184
\c@table=\count185
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/babel\babel.sty
Package: babel 2020/12/16 3.52 The Babel package

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/babel\babel.def
File: babel.def 2020/12/16 3.52 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count186
\U@D=\dimen139
\l@babelnohyphens=\language79

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/babel\txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count187

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cfg
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/babel-german\german.ldf
Language: german 2020/07/21 v2.12 German support for babel (pre-1996 orthograph
y)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/babel-german\germanb.ldf
Language: germanb 2020/07/21 v2.12 German support for babel (pre-1996 orthograp
hy)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 135.
))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/babel-english\english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
Package babel Info: \l@canadian = using hyphenrules for english
(babel)             (\language0) on input line 102.
Package babel Info: \l@australian = using hyphenrules for ukenglish
(babel)             (\language73) on input line 105.
Package babel Info: \l@newzealand = using hyphenrules for ukenglish
(babel)             (\language73) on input line 108.
))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/colortbl\colortbl.sty
Package: colortbl 2020/01/04 v1.0e Color table columns (DPC)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tools\array.sty
Package: array 2019/08/31 v2.4l Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen140
\ar@mcellbox=\box47
\extrarowheight=\dimen141
\NC@list=\toks15
\extratabsurround=\skip49
\backup@length=\skip50
\ar@cellbox=\box48
)
\everycr=\toks16
\minrowclearance=\skip51
)
\rownum=\count188
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/graphics\dvipsnam.def
File: dvipsnam.def 2016/06/17 v3.0m Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count189
\Gm@cntv=\count190
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count191
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen142
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen143
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen144
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen145
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen146
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen147
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen148
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen149
\Gm@dimlist=\toks18

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/titlesec\titlesec.sty
Package: titlesec 2019/10/16 v2.13 Sectioning titles
\ttl@box=\box49
\beforetitleunit=\skip52
\aftertitleunit=\skip53
\ttl@plus=\dimen150
\ttl@minus=\dimen151
\ttl@toksa=\toks19
\titlewidth=\dimen152
\titlewidthlast=\dimen153
\titlewidthfirst=\dimen154
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer\tikz.sty
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf.sty
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.sty
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks20
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen155
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen156

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box50
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
))
Package: pgf 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.sty
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen157
\Gin@req@width=\dimen158
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.sty
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks21
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks22

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks23
))
\pgf@x=\dimen159
\pgf@y=\dimen160
\pgf@xa=\dimen161
\pgf@ya=\dimen162
\pgf@xb=\dimen163
\pgf@yb=\dimen164
\pgf@xc=\dimen165
\pgf@yc=\dimen166
\pgf@xd=\dimen167
\pgf@yd=\dimen168
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read3
\c@pgf@counta=\count192
\c@pgf@countb=\count193
\c@pgf@countc=\count194
\c@pgf@countd=\count195
\t@pgf@toka=\toks24
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks25
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks26
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count196
 (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
)))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count197
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count198
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
)) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen169
\pgfmath@count=\count199
\pgfmath@box=\box51
\pgfmath@toks=\toks27
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks28
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks29
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count266
))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.tex)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen170
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen171
\pgf@picminy=\dimen172
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen173
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen174
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen175
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen176
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen177
\pgf@xx=\dimen178
\pgf@xy=\dimen179
\pgf@yx=\dimen180
\pgf@yy=\dimen181
\pgf@zx=\dimen182
\pgf@zy=\dimen183
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen184
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen185
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.te
x
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen186
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen187
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
\pgfpic=\box52
\pgf@hbox=\box53
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box54
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count267
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen188
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen189
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen190
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen191
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen192
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
\pgf@max=\dimen193
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count268
\pgf@shadingcount=\count269
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box55
))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
))) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.te
x
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box56
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.st
y
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen194
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen195
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.st
y
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
)) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.sty
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.sty
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen196
\pgffor@skip=\dimen197
\pgffor@stack=\toks30
\pgffor@toks=\toks31
))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz\tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.co
de.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count270
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen198
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen199
\tikz@lasty=\dimen256
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen257
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen258
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen259
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen260
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen261
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen262
\tikz@figbox=\box57
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box58
\tikz@tempbox=\box59
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box60
\tikztreelevel=\count271
\tikznumberofchildren=\count272
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count273
\tikz@fig@count=\count274

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count275
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count276
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count277
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count278

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzli
brarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
)))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty
Package: fancyhdr 2019/01/31 v3.10 Extensive control of page headers and footer
s
\f@nch@headwidth=\skip54
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip55
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip56
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip57
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip58
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip59
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip60
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip61
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip62
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count279
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks32
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/ragged2e\ragged2e.sty
Package: ragged2e 2019/07/28 v2.2 ragged2e Package (MS)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/ms\everysel.sty
Package: everysel 2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
)
\CenteringLeftskip=\skip63
\RaggedLeftLeftskip=\skip64
\RaggedRightLeftskip=\skip65
\CenteringRightskip=\skip66
\RaggedLeftRightskip=\skip67
\RaggedRightRightskip=\skip68
\CenteringParfillskip=\skip69
\RaggedLeftParfillskip=\skip70
\RaggedRightParfillskip=\skip71
\JustifyingParfillskip=\skip72
\CenteringParindent=\skip73
\RaggedLeftParindent=\skip74
\RaggedRightParindent=\skip75
\JustifyingParindent=\skip76
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/shipunov\boldline.sty
Package: boldline 2008/02/04 v0.2 Adjust line width in tables
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/catchfilebetweentags\catchfilebetweentags
.sty
Package: catchfilebetweentags 2011/02/19 v1.1 - Catch file between tags (FC)
 (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/etex-pkg\etex.sty
Package: etex 2016/08/01 v2.7 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)


Package etex Warning: Extended allocation already in use.
(etex)                etex.sty code will not be used.
(etex)                To force etex package to load, add
(etex)                \RequirePackage{etex}
(etex)                at the start of the document.

) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/catchfile\catchfile.sty
Package: catchfile 2019/12/09 v1.8 Catch the contents of a file (HO)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
))
\CatchFBT@tok=\toks33
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/enumitem\enumitem.sty
Package: enumitem 2019/06/20 v3.9 Customized lists
\labelindent=\skip77
\enit@outerparindent=\dimen263
\enit@toks=\toks34
\enit@inbox=\box61
\enit@count@id=\count280
\enitdp@description=\count281
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/fontawesome\fontawesome.sty
Package: fontawesome 2016/05/15 v4.6.3.1 font awesome icons

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/iftex\ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/fontawesome\fontawesomesymbols-generic.te
x)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/fontawesome\fontawesomesymbols-pdftex.tex
)) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/fourier\fourier.sty
Package: fourier 2020/03/03 2.2 fourier-GUTenberg package
Now handling font encoding FML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding FML
Now handling font encoding FMS ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding FMS
Now handling font encoding FMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding FMX

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+futs on input line 1
12.

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/fourier\t1futs.fd
File: t1futs.fd 2004/03/02 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for T1/futs.
))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/fourier\fourier-orns.sty
Package: fourier-orns 2020/03/03 2.2 fourier-ornaments package
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 63.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `T1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 63.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> T1/futs/m/n on input line 63.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `T1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 63.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/futs/m/n on input line 63.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  T1/futs/m/n --> T1/futs/b/n on input line 64.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `letters' on input line 72.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OML' has changed to `FML' for symbol font
(Font)              `letters' in the math version `normal' on input line 72.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> FML/futmi/m/it on input line 72.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OML' has changed to `FML' for symbol font
(Font)              `letters' in the math version `bold' on input line 72.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> FML/futmi/m/it on input line 72.
\symotherletters=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  FML/futmi/m/it --> FML/futmi/b/it on input line 74.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `otherletters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  FML/futm/m/it --> FML/futm/b/it on input line 75.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 76.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 77.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 78.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 79.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 80.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 81.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 82.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 83.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 84.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 85.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 86.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `symbols' on input line 126.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMS' has changed to `FMS' for symbol font
(Font)              `symbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 126.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> FMS/futm/m/n on input line 126.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMS' has changed to `FMS' for symbol font
(Font)              `symbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 126.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> FMS/futm/m/n on input line 126.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line 127.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `FMX' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 1
27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> FMX/futm/m/n on input line 127.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `FMX' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 127
.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> FMX/futm/m/n on input line 127.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 128.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/futs/bx/n on input line 128.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/futs/bx/n on input line 128.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathrm on input line 129.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathit on input line 130.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> T1/futs/m/it on input line 130.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> T1/futs/m/it on input line 130.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathcal on input line 131.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varkappa on input line 132.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \leqslant on input line 138.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \geqslant on input line 139.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \vDash on input line 142.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \blacktriangleleft on input line 14
3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \blacktriangleright on input line 1
44.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \nleqslant on input line 145.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \ngeqslant on input line 146.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \parallel on input line 147.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \nparallel on input line 148.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \nvDash on input line 150.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \intercal on input line 151.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hslash on input line 152.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \nexists on input line 153.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \complement on input line 154.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varsubsetneq on input line 155.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 161.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \smallsetminus on input line 162.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \subsetneqq on input line 163.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \rightrightarrows on input line 164
.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \leftleftarrows on input line 165.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \square on input line 166.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \curvearrowleft on input line 167.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \curvearrowright on input line 168.

LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \blacksquare on input line 169.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varkappa on input line 199.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \varvarrho on input line 200.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \Vert on input line 223.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \vert on input line 228.
```

Answer (score 0):

Log Part 2

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \Downarrow on input line 238.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \backslash on input line 240.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rangle on input line 242.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \langle on input line 244.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rbrace on input line 246.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lbrace on input line 248.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rceil on input line 250.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lceil on input line 252.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rfloor on input line 254.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lfloor on input line 256.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 260.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 261.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 262.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 263.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 264.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 265.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 266.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 267.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 268.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 269.
\symUfutm=\mathgroup7
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hypertext links for LaTeX

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen264
\Hy@linkcounter=\count282
\Hy@pagecounter=\count283

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count284
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4464.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4469.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4472.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4479.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4484.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4717.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count285

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5076.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen265

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count286
\Field@Width=\dimen266
\Fld@charsize=\dimen267
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6347.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6352.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6355.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6362.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6367.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6372.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6377.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6417.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6421.

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2020/08/17 v1.0a Emulation of the original atbegshi packa
ge
with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count287
\c@Item=\count288
\c@Hfootnote=\count289
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref driver for pdfTeX

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery packag
e
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count290
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count291

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/uniquecounter\uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip78
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2020/08/01 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks35
\inpenc@posthook=\toks36
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/lineno\lineno.sty
Package: lineno 2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
\linenopenalty=\count292
\output=\toks37
\linenoprevgraf=\count293
\linenumbersep=\dimen268
\linenumberwidth=\dimen269
\c@linenumber=\count294
\c@pagewiselinenumber=\count295
\c@LN@truepage=\count296
\c@internallinenumber=\count297
\c@internallinenumbers=\count298
\quotelinenumbersep=\dimen270
\bframerule=\dimen271
\bframesep=\dimen272
\bframebox=\box62
LaTeX Info: Redefining \\ on input line 3056.
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/lipsum\lipsum.sty
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2020-12-07 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count299
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box63
))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2020-10-27 L3 Experimental document command parser

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse-generic.tex))
Package: lipsum 2019/01/02 v2.2 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/lipsum\lipsum.ltd.tex
File: lipsum.ltd.tex 2019/01/02 v2.2 The Lorem ipsum dummy text
))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tools\longtable.sty
Package: longtable 2020/01/07 v4.13 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip79
\LTright=\skip80
\LTpre=\skip81
\LTpost=\skip82
\LTchunksize=\count300
\LTcapwidth=\dimen273
\LT@head=\box64
\LT@firsthead=\box65
\LT@foot=\box66
\LT@lastfoot=\box67
\LT@cols=\count301
\LT@rows=\count302
\c@LT@tables=\count303
\c@LT@chunks=\count304
\LT@p@ftn=\toks38
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/makecell\makecell.sty
Package: makecell 2009/08/03 V0.1e Managing of Tab Column Heads and Cells
\rotheadsize=\dimen274
\c@nlinenum=\count305
\TeXr@lab=\toks39
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/marvosym\marvosym.sty
Package: marvosym 2011/07/20 v2.2 Martin Vogel's Symbols font definitions
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tools\multicol.sty
Package: multicol 2019/12/09 v1.8y multicolumn formatting (FMi)
\c@tracingmulticols=\count306
\mult@box=\box68
\multicol@leftmargin=\dimen275
\c@unbalance=\count307
\c@collectmore=\count308
\doublecol@number=\count309
\multicoltolerance=\count310
\multicolpretolerance=\count311
\full@width=\dimen276
\page@free=\dimen277
\premulticols=\dimen278
\postmulticols=\dimen279
\multicolsep=\skip83
\multicolbaselineskip=\skip84
\partial@page=\box69
\last@line=\box70
\maxbalancingoverflow=\dimen280
\mult@rightbox=\box71
\mult@grightbox=\box72
\mult@gfirstbox=\box73
\mult@firstbox=\box74
\@tempa=\box75
\@tempa=\box76
\@tempa=\box77
\@tempa=\box78
\@tempa=\box79
\@tempa=\box80
\@tempa=\box81
\@tempa=\box82
\@tempa=\box83
\@tempa=\box84
\@tempa=\box85
\@tempa=\box86
\@tempa=\box87
\@tempa=\box88
\@tempa=\box89
\@tempa=\box90
\@tempa=\box91
\@tempa=\box92
\@tempa=\box93
\@tempa=\box94
\@tempa=\box95
\@tempa=\box96
\@tempa=\box97
\@tempa=\box98
\@tempa=\box99
\@tempa=\box100
\@tempa=\box101
\@tempa=\box102
\@tempa=\box103
\@tempa=\box104
\@tempa=\box105
\@tempa=\box106
\@tempa=\box107
\@tempa=\box108
\@tempa=\box109
\@tempa=\box110
\@tempa=\box111
\c@minrows=\count312
\c@columnbadness=\count313
\c@finalcolumnbadness=\count314
\last@try=\dimen281
\multicolovershoot=\dimen282
\multicolundershoot=\dimen283
\mult@nat@firstbox=\box112
\colbreak@box=\box113
\mc@col@check@num=\count315
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/multirow\multirow.sty
Package: multirow 2019/05/31 v2.5 Span multiple rows of a table
\multirow@colwidth=\skip85
\multirow@cntb=\count316
\multirow@dima=\skip86
\bigstrutjot=\dimen284
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/pdfpages\pdfpages.sty
Package: pdfpages 2020/01/28 v0.5q Insert pages of external PDF documents (AM)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tools\calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count317
\calc@Bcount=\count318
\calc@Adimen=\dimen285
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen286
\calc@Askip=\skip87
\calc@Bskip=\skip88
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count319
\calc@Cskip=\skip89
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/eso-pic\eso-pic.sty
Package: eso-pic 2020/10/14 v3.0a eso-pic (RN)
\ESO@tempdima=\dimen287
\ESO@tempdimb=\dimen288
)
\AM@pagewidth=\dimen289
\AM@pageheight=\dimen290

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/pdfpages\pppdftex.def
File: pppdftex.def 2020/01/28 v0.5q Pdfpages driver for pdfTeX (AM)
)
\AM@pagebox=\box114
\AM@global@opts=\toks40
\AM@pagecnt=\count320
\AM@toc@title=\toks41
\c@AM@survey=\count321
\AM@templatesizebox=\box115
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/psnfss\pifont.sty
Package: pifont 2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3 Pi font support (SPQR) 
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+pzd on input line 63.


(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/psnfss\upzd.fd
File: upzd.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for U/pzd.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+psy on input line 64.


(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/psnfss\upsy.fd
File: upsy.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for U/psy.
))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/caption\subcaption.sty
Package: subcaption 2020/10/07 v1.3j Sub-captions (AR)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/caption\caption.sty
Package: caption 2020/10/26 v3.5g Customizing captions (AR)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/caption\caption3.sty
Package: caption3 2020/10/21 v2.2e caption3 kernel (AR)
\captionmargin=\dimen291
\captionmargin@=\dimen292
\captionwidth=\dimen293
\caption@tempdima=\dimen294
\caption@indent=\dimen295
\caption@parindent=\dimen296
\caption@hangindent=\dimen297
Package caption Info: Standard document class detected.
)
\c@caption@flags=\count322
\c@continuedfloat=\count323
Package caption Info: hyperref package is loaded.
Package caption Info: longtable package is loaded.

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/caption\ltcaption.sty
Package: ltcaption 2020/05/30 v1.4b longtable captions (AR)
))
\c@subfigure=\count324
\c@subtable=\count325
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tools\tabularx.sty
Package: tabularx 2020/01/15 v2.11c `tabularx' package (DPC)
\TX@col@width=\dimen298
\TX@old@table=\dimen299
\TX@old@col=\dimen300
\TX@target=\dimen301
\TX@delta=\dimen302
\TX@cols=\count326
\TX@ftn=\toks42
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcolorbox.sty
Package: tcolorbox 2020/10/09 version 4.42 text color boxes

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tools\verbatim.sty
Package: verbatim 2019/11/10 v1.5r LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
\every@verbatim=\toks43
\verbatim@line=\toks44
\verbatim@in@stream=\read4
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/environ\environ.sty
Package: environ 2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/trimspaces\trimspaces.sty
Package: trimspaces 2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
)
\@envbody=\toks45
)
\tcb@titlebox=\box116
\tcb@upperbox=\box117
\tcb@lowerbox=\box118
\tcb@phantombox=\box119
\c@tcbbreakpart=\count327
\c@tcblayer=\count328
\c@tcolorbox@number=\count329
\tcb@temp=\box120
\tcb@temp=\box121
\tcb@temp=\box122
\tcb@temp=\box123
\tcb@out=\write4
\tcb@record@out=\write5

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbraster.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbraster.code.tex' version '4.42'
\c@tcbrastercolumn=\count330
\c@tcbrasterrow=\count331
\c@tcbraster=\count332
) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbskins.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskins.code.tex' version '4.42'
\tcb@waterbox=\box124
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskinsjigsaw.code.tex' version '4.42'
)) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbbreakable.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbbreakable.code.tex' version '4.42'
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/oberdiek\pdfcol.sty
Package: pdfcol 2019/12/29 v1.6 Handle new color stacks for pdfTeX (HO)
)
Package pdfcol Info: New color stack `tcb@breakable' = 1 on input line 23.
\tcb@testbox=\box125
\tcb@totalupperbox=\box126
\tcb@totallowerbox=\box127
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbhooks.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbhooks.code.tex' version '4.42'
) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbtheorems.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbtheorems.code.tex' version '4.42'
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2020/09/23 v2.17i AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip90

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks46
\ex@=\dimen303
))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen304
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count333
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count334
\leftroot@=\count335
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count336
\DOTSCASE@=\count337
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box128
\strutbox@=\box129
\big@size=\dimen305
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count338
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count339
\dotsspace@=\muskip17
\c@parentequation=\count340
\dspbrk@lvl=\count341
\tag@help=\toks47
\row@=\count342
\column@=\count343
\maxfields@=\count344
\andhelp@=\toks48
\eqnshift@=\dimen306
\alignsep@=\dimen307
\tagshift@=\dimen308
\tagwidth@=\dimen309
\totwidth@=\dimen310
\lineht@=\dimen311
\@envbody=\toks49
\multlinegap=\skip91
\multlinetaggap=\skip92
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks50
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbfitting.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbfitting.code.tex' version '4.42'
\tcbfitdim=\dimen312
\tcb@lowerfitdim=\dimen313
\tcb@upperfitdim=\dimen314
\tcb@cur@hbadness=\count345
) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbxparse.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbxparse.code.tex' version '4.42'
) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcblistingsutf8.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingsutf8.code.tex' version '4.42'
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcblistings.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistings.code.tex' version '4.42'
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/listings\listings.sty
\lst@mode=\count346
\lst@gtempboxa=\box130
\lst@token=\toks51
\lst@length=\count347
\lst@currlwidth=\dimen315
\lst@column=\count348
\lst@pos=\count349
\lst@lostspace=\dimen316
\lst@width=\dimen317
\lst@newlines=\count350
\lst@lineno=\count351
\lst@maxwidth=\dimen318

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/listings\lstmisc.sty
File: lstmisc.sty 2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
\c@lstnumber=\count352
\lst@skipnumbers=\count353
\lst@framebox=\box131
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/listings\listings.cfg
File: listings.cfg 2020/03/24 1.8d listings configuration
))
Package: listings 2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcblistingscore.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingscore.code.tex' version '4.42'
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbprocessing.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbprocessing.code.tex' version '4.42'
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 77.
))
\c@tcblisting=\count354
))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/listingsutf8\listingsutf8.sty
Package: listingsutf8 2019-12-10 v1.5 Allow UTF-8 in listings input (HO)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/stringenc\stringenc.sty
Package: stringenc 2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO
)
)))
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbexternal.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbexternal.code.tex' version '4.42'
) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbmagazine.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbmagazine.code.tex' version '4.42'
) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbvignette.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbvignette.code.tex' version '4.42'

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzli
braryfadings.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryfadings.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryfadings.code.te
x
File: pgflibraryfadings.code.tex 2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
))) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/tcolorbox\tcbposter.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbposter.code.tex' version '4.42'
)) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/ulem\ulem.sty
\UL@box=\box132
\UL@hyphenbox=\box133
\UL@skip=\skip93
\UL@hook=\toks52
\UL@height=\dimen319
\UL@pe=\count355
\UL@pixel=\dimen320
\ULC@box=\box134
Package: ulem 2019/11/18
\ULdepth=\dimen321
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/wasysym\wasysym.sty
Package: wasysym 2020/01/19 v2.4 Wasy-2 symbol support package
\symwasy=\mathgroup8
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `wasy' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/wasy/m/n --> U/wasy/b/n on input line 93.
)
\R=\dimen322
) (fullY1.aux)
\openout1 = `fullY1.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for FML/futm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for FML+futm on input line 
6.

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/fourier\fmlfutm.fd
File: fmlfutm.fd 2004/10/30 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for FML/futm.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for FMS/futm/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for FMS+futm on input line 
6.

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/fourier\fmsfutm.fd
File: fmsfutm.fd 2004/10/30 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for FMS/futm.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for FMX/futm/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for FMX+futm on input line 
6.

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/fourier\fmxfutm.fd
File: fmxfutm.fd futm-extension
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count356
\scratchdimen=\dimen323
\scratchbox=\box135
\nofMPsegments=\count357
\nofMParguments=\count358
\everyMPshowfont=\toks53
\MPscratchCnt=\count359
\MPscratchDim=\dimen324
\MPnumerator=\count360
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count361
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks54
) (C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: twoside 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(71.13188pt, 455.24411pt, 71.13188pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(56.9055pt, 731.23584pt, 56.9055pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=455.24411pt
* \textheight=731.23584pt
* \oddsidemargin=-1.1381pt
* \evensidemargin=-1.1381pt
* \topmargin=-45.43198pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=18.06749pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=25.29494pt
* \marginparwidth=125.0pt
* \marginparsep=7.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros
LaTeX Info: Redefining \selectfont on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \widehat on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \widetilde on input line 6.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6.

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/generic/gettitlestring\gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count362
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 6.

(fullY1.out) (fullY1.out)
\@outlinefile=\write6
\openout6 = `fullY1.out'.


(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/pdflscape\pdflscape.sty
Package: pdflscape 2019/12/05 v0.12 Display of landscape pages in PDF (HO)

(C:\MerlinsProgs\tex\miktex\tex/latex/graphics\lscape.sty
Package: lscape 2020/05/28 v3.02 Landscape Pages (DPC)
)
Package pdflscape Info: Auto-detected driver: pdftex on input line 81.
)
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: listings package is loaded.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
\c@lstlisting=\count363

Chapter 1.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\\' on input line 8.

[1


{C:/Users/merli/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (fullY1.aux)
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `fullY1.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: 65002F524688ABB7C7496ED6F29033B5;325.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 30849 strings out of 479696
 585768 string characters out of 2875610
 1020039 words of memory out of 3000000
 47292 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 472924 words of font info for 71 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 122i,5n,124p,451b,350s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
{C:/MerlinsProgs/tex/miktex/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}<C:/MerlinsProgs/tex/
miktex/fonts/type1/adobe/utopia/putr8a.pfb><C:/MerlinsProgs/tex/miktex/fonts/ty
pe1/adobe/utopia/putri8a.pfb>
Output written on fullY1.pdf (1 page, 44282 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 76 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 6 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 189 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```